# Focus on the second textfield Wicket

Tags: java, wicket, form-submit

I have got 2 sets of search textfield:

The first textfield is working fine when I tried a submission using the return key(Enter). However, when the second textfield was typed in and the return key was pressed, the first textfield was excuted.

I tried to set the focus to the second textfield as followed :

```
    secondTextField = new TextField("secondTextField", new Model()){
        @Override
        protected void onComponentTag(ComponentTag tag)
        {
                super.onComponentTag(tag);

                tag.put("onclick", "getelementbyid('"+secondTextField.getMarkupId()+"').focus()");

        } 
    };

    form.add(secondTextField);
```

But this isn't working. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you be a bit clearer about what you are trying to accomplish? What does the first text field look like? Are you trying to add behavior to a form submission (because if so, that's where you'd want this behavior). Right now, it looks like you are setting up the second text field so it gets the focus when it is clicked on.

Comment: @ig0774 They are basically two search boxes which come with there own submit button. What I have been trying to accomplish is to be able to enter a text into the second search textbox and use the enter key to perform the search instead of clicking on its submit button. At the moment every time I press enter, the submit button of the first search textbox is operated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless defined otherwise, almost every browser submits the current form by the first available button on enter key. So if you want to use another button you'll have to decorate your TextField with JavaScript to capture the Enter Key, submit the form using the appropriate Button and (this is important) return false.

You might be able to work around this by separating the two TextFields into separate Forms (if that's possible) but that's just a guess, as I can't try this at the moment.

The following code, if added to a TextField prevents the Enter key from triggering a form submit. You'll have to adapt it to submit by a specific button.

```
/**
 * Behavior that traps the enter key press
 *
 * @author ivaynberg
 */
public class EnterKeyTrap extends Behavior implements IHeaderContributor {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -410239548482332706L;

    @Override
    public void onComponentTag(Component component, ComponentTag tag) {
        tag.put("onkeydown", "return ekt(event)!=13");
    }

    public void renderHead(IHeaderResponse response) {
        response.renderJavaScript("function ekt(e){if(typeof(e.keyCode)==\"undefined\"){return e.which;}else{return e.keyCode;}}", "EnterKeyTrap");
    }

}
```